# Multiple matches with Postgres regexp_matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

I trying to use Postgres regexp_matches function to pull hashtags out of a string... The following example returns only a match - how do I extract both hashtags?

```
regexp_matches("Hello #world #planet", '#([A-Za-z0-9]+)')
```

Cheers, 
Andrei

Comment: try with `g` flag as `regexp_matches("Hello #world #planet", '#([A-Za-z0-9]+)', 'g')`

Comment: @rock321987 thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should enclose string literal with `'` not `"`. Adding `'g'` as proposed in comment should help:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('Hello #world #planet', '#([A-Za-z0-9]+)', 'g')
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7455/0)**</kbd>

```
╔════════════════╗
║ regexp_matches ║
╠════════════════╣
║ world          ║
║ planet         ║
╚════════════════╝
```

Comment: thanks for your help. My biggest issue was that I was using regexp_matches inside the WHERE clause which didn't return the results I expected.